# Почему нейросети обучаются на наших субъективных данных?

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Например, изображения. Зачем мы обучаем нейросети на картинках RGB модели, если с физической точки зрения у объектов нет свойства цвет.

Если нейросеть выявляет или создает в процессе обучения непонятные человеку закономерности, то почему же она сама должна учится на понятных нам данных?

Почему например вместо цвета, мы не кодируем все изображения (для обучения) используя термографию или например, отклик объекта на звуковые колебания разных частот и т.д.?

Answer (score 0):

Нейросеть это не мозг. Это просто одна большая алгебраическая функция, для которой мы подгоняем аргументы так, что бы на определённые входные данные она выдавала определённый желаемый результат.

Практически все камеры работают с изображениями как с набором пикселей. Можно представлять изображение хоть в виде волн, хоть в виде массива из `rgb` значений, главное что бы имелись хоть какие ни будь закономерности между изменением входных и выходных данных. А следовательно лишнее преобразование из одного формата изображение в другое просто бессмысленно (оно ещё скорее всего данные сотрёт) (хотя иногда в целях упрощения обучения можно например сделать картинку ЧБ, если нейросеть распознаёт например не цвет, а форму)

Человек видит на подсознательном уровне. Нам не надо вручную анализировать **каждую** колбочку в глазе, что бы понять, что мы видим. Мозг перевёл эту задачу в раздел подсознательное, и из за этого мы и не можем понять точный алгоритм распознавания, а если и можем, то он получается слишком сложным.

Нейросеть учится искать закономерности между данными `A` и данными `B`, и всё

И так же прошу заметить, что нейросеть не всегда получает данные, которые понятны и нам. Например графики: передавать в нейросеть изображение с графиком - слишком дорого. Мы передаём ей огромный массив чисел. Опять же, используем для обучения мы ту информацию, которая у нас имеется, и преобразовывать её в какую то более другую - смысла не имеет